# How to overcome Salesforce System Error when deploying from Apex Code more than 1488 Metadata Records?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, custom-metadata

Conversion process of custom object records into Custom Metadata records using [Metadata.Operations class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Metadata_Operations.htm#apex_class_Metadata_Operations) enqueueDeployment method fails if deployment container contains more than 1488 records.
[image]
However, this process is executed successfully if deployment container contains 1488 records or less
[image]

I receive different Gack Ids 882046342, -1760255134 and 29825863 when I try to deploy different amount of records.

I use the following code to convert and deploy custom metadata records
https://gist.github.com/Patlatus/53ce49fde265c0aa3d0f2c3fdda8b900

```
public class MD {
    public static List<String> getItems(List<String> parts, Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldsMap, SObject r) {
        List<String> items = new List<String>();
        for (String part: parts) {
            items.add( fieldsMap.containsKey( part ) ? String.valueOf( r.get( part ) ) : part );
        }
        return items;
    }    
    public static Id updateAndDeployMetadata(List<SObject> sourceRecords, SObjectType dest, Map<SObjectField, SObjectField> mappings, String fullNameDef, String labelDef) {
        Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
        String destName = dest.getDescribe().getName();
        List<String> fullNameParts = fullNameDef.split('\\+');
        List<String> labelParts = labelDef.split('\\+');
        if( sourceRecords != null && !sourceRecords.isEmpty() ) {
            Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fields = sourceRecords[0].getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();
            for (SObject r: sourceRecords ) {
                Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata =  new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
                customMetadata.fullName = destName + '.' + String.join( getItems(fullNameParts, fields, r), '');
                customMetadata.label = String.join( getItems(labelParts, fields, r), '').left(40);
                for (SObjectField key: mappings.keySet() ) {
                    Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
                    customField.field = String.valueOf( mappings.get(key) );
                    customField.value = r.get(key);
                    customMetadata.values.add(customField);
                }
                mdContainer.addMetadata(customMetadata);
            }
            return Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, null);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

https://gist.github.com/Patlatus/bb4c964f72ddfb60bbd4710bb34597b9

```
MD.updateAndDeployMetadata(
[ SELECT Field1__c, Field2__c, Field3__c, Field4__c FROM Object__c   ],
CustomMetadata__mdt.sObjectType,
new Map<SObjectField, SObjectField>{
Object__c.Field1__c=> CustomMetadata__mdt.Field1__c,
Object__c.Field2__c=> CustomMetadata__mdt.Field2__c,
Object__c.Field3__c=> CustomMetadata__mdt.Field3__c,
Object__c.Field4__c => CustomMetadata__mdt.Field4__c 
},
'X+Field1__c+_+Field2__c',
'Field3__c+ +Field4__c '
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[I solved this problem by splitting records into chunks of 1000 records and deploying them separately.](https://patlatus.wordpress.com/2018/10/18/convert-custom-object-records-to-custom-metadata-records/)

I have one field with unique values. So I order my records by that field and write down values of 1000th, 2000th, 3000th and 4000th records

```
List rs = [ SELECT UniqueField__c FROM Object__c ORDER BY UniqueField__c ASC ];
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, ‘@@@ v: ‘ + rs[1000] );
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, ‘@@@ v: ‘ + rs[2000] );
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, ‘@@@ v: ‘ + rs[3000] );
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, ‘@@@ v: ‘ + rs[4000] );
```

Then I just modify my code to include where clause `WHERE UniqueField__c > ‘value1000’ AND UniqueField__c <= 'value2000' ORDER BY UniqueField__c ASC` and execute it five times with different threshold values corresponding to values of UniqueField__c on 1000th, 2000th, 3000th and 4000th records.